# Python performance on reading sas dataset vs sql server table

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, sas

Does anyone have any benchmark or comparison on which one is faster in terms of using pandas to pull data from a sas dataset vs sql server?

Any thoughts or inputs is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you have a choice use the SQL server. SAS format is proprietary and locked down, the import packages known are not all bug free.

Comment: They're both proprietary formats.  There might be better third party support for `.mdf` files, but I wouldn't rely on it.